# How can I allow ERC20 token payment inside javascript function

Tags: solidity, react

I'm working on a smart contract that allows users to pay for monthly subscriptions like Netflix, Amazon, etc... with ERC20 tokens.

Everything works well when I tested it. but when I implemented the pay function inside the front-end, so users can interact with the smart contract. the problem that I've faced is that when I clicked on a button to fire off the pay function, I had Metamask asking to confirm the approval, then once the approval is confirmed, I had to confirm the transfer of tokens. **I had to confirm the transfer of tokens. **then I got another transaction to confirm the equivalent amount of tokens in ETH.**

I made a lot of research but I got stuck, on can I allow the pay function to transfer tokens between two addresses only once.
***am I missing something?***

PS: blockchain.account & blockchain.smartContract are imported from redux object state.

***solidity function***

```
function pay(uint planId) external {
    Subscription storage subscription = subscriptions[subscriber][planId];
    Plan storage plan = plans[planId];
    IERC20 token = IERC20(plan.token);
    require(
      block.timestamp > subscription.nextPayment,
      'not due yet'
    );

    token.transferFrom(subscriber, plan.merchant, plan.amount);  
    emit PaymentSent(
      msg.sender,
      plan.merchant, 
      plan.amount, 
      planId, 
      block.timestamp
    );
    subscription.nextPayment = subscription.nextPayment + plan.frequency;
  }
```

***React function***

```
async function pay() {
    showAlert(true, "Happy to see you, Your payment is processing...!");
    const data = await blockchain.smartContract.methods.subscriptions(Id).call();
    let monthlyPayment = String(data.monthlyPayment);
    let tokenAddress = data.amount;

    // instance of ERC20 contract
    let currency = new web3.eth.Contract(tokenIbi, tokenAddress);
    
    currency.methods.approve("0x1b4eAe2DC7Ca0b68643A26177bfC9c069B3D6E04",
                              amount).send({from: blockchain.account})
    .then(
      await currency.methods.transfer("0x1b4eAe2DC7Ca0b68643A26177bfC9c069B3D6E04",
                              amount).send({from:blockchain.account})
    )
    blockchain.smartContract.methods.pay(Id).send({from: blockchain.account})
    .once("error", (err)=> {
      console.log(err);
      showAlert(true, "Something went wrong...!");
    })
    .then((receipt)=> {
      console.log(receipt);
      showAlert(true, "Congratulations, You monthly payment has been submitted successfully");
      dispatch(fetchData(blockchain.account));
    })
  }
```

***Pay button***

```
<button className="btn"
                        id="launchApp-btn"
                        onClick={(e)=> {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        pay();
                    }}>
```

Comment: Could you clarify in simpler terms what happens vs what you want to happen?

Comment: Usually U need 2 tx if you interacting with a contract that use transferFrom. Approve tx and pay(trigger transfer)tx. There is however an EIP to use signatures instead of approve tx but the erc20 contract of the used token must support it

Comment: You are having 3 transactions. You don’t need to use the transfer method in your JavaScript code, the pay method will transfer the token on your behalf, that is the point of approving first

Comment: @MajdTL I tried your solution but it didn't work...

Comment: You are transferring token twice. First using the transfer function and then using the pay function. Use await instead of „.then(..)“ give you a better view at what you are doing

Comment: @MajdTL Thanks for your efforts!! yes, It was just that I'm transferring the token twice. I fixed that and it worked. thanks again